# Can't figure out how to make this PHP Array table

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, html-table

I can't seem to figure out how to print a nice ordered table.

I want there to be a max of 7 columns and it can generate as many rows as it needs to depending on the size of the array. The array is via a URL that can be updated at any time. (Its a players inventory on steam).

```
$id = $steamprofile['steamid'];
$key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
if($id != null){
  $inv = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$id.'/inventory/json/730/2');
  $inventory = json_decode($inv, true);

  $price = file_get_contents('values/response.json');
  $value = json_decode($price, true);

  foreach ($inventory['rgDescriptions'] as $rgDescription) {                                
    for($i = 0; sizeof($rgDescription['market_name']) > $i; $i++){
      if(isset($rgDescription['market_name'])){
        print '<td><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/'.$rgDescription['icon_url'].'" alt="'.$rgDescription['market_name'].' width="80" height="75"></td>';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The array is located [here](http://steamcommunity.com/id/csgoaddict/inventory/json/730/2) if you need to see it.

I can print out the table but it always repeats the items which I don't want. So how do I solve this? Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: That JSON is utterly unreadable the way it is since browser will escape indentation. Can you paste in code formatting here, inside your question, the relevant part of it?

Comment: First , print your table like :
echo '<pre>' , print_r($inventory , true) , '</pre>'; 
And see if your code match fine with what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to count columns:

```
$max = 7;
$col = 1;
for(...) {
   if ($col == 1) {
      echo '<tr>'; // start new row if on column #1
   }
   echo '<td><img etc....'; // output a column
   if ($col == $max) {
     echo '</tr>'; // if column $max was just output, end the row
     $col = 0; // reset column count, 0 to account for ++ coming up next
   }
   $col++;
}
```

Comment: So simple thank you, for some reason I just couldn't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

`"market_name"` is not an array, but an element of one. If you `count` it (which is the same of `sizeof`), it'll return `1` as it only has one value assigned to it. Said that, your line `for($i = 0; sizeof($rgDescription['market_name']) > $i; $i++)` is the same as `for($i = 0; 1 > $i; $i++)`, returning just the same result, always.

The `foreach` plays the repetition part and then you get a huge table with the same lines.

**Suggestions:**

```
foreach ($inventory['rgDescriptions'] as $rgDescription) {                                
    foreach ($rgDescription as $rg) {
        if(isset($rg['market_name'])) {
            print('
                <td>
                    <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/'
                    .$rgDescription['icon_url'].
                    '" alt="'.$rgDescription['market_name'].
                    ' width="80" height="75"></td>');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, it was basically copy paste from another section of my site where I was pulling out the array from there and didn't over look it. The second foreach isnt needed.